# The WiFi adapter (Chipset Realtek 8821ce) is not found after upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04, realtek-wireless

I have Ubuntu 18.04 , the WiFi adapter is not found - Chipset realtek 8821ce

The WiFi adapter worked fine in Ububtu 16.04

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.